# Wordpress logged in but no access to wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, login, errors, 404-error

Using Apache 2.2, Wordpress 4.4, Better WP Security. I have logged in, can browse all pages on front-end, but when I try to access any link that is on wp-admin I get 404 page.
I don't have any ideas left for this situation.

I've tried with no luck to:

- disable plugins, as just BWS, and all plugins
- delete/reset .htaccess,
- set all folders and files to 777
- looked into table itsec_lockout but there's no my IP address
- searched sql table itsec_log and what I get for my IP in log_data is `a:1:{s:12:"query_string";s:0:"";}`, what is that?

What is left to try?

Comment: and you can access any other page in the front-end ?

Comment: Yes I can, and logged in and logged out. With no difference.

Comment: and why do you use 4.4, 4.7 is much too expensive or?

Comment: Because it is possible that website will brake due to plugins and theme setup. I haven't work on website development, so don't know what is modified.

Comment: OK fair enough, have you enabled the error log?

Comment: Did you enable the Hide Backend feature in Better WP Security Plugin?

Comment: Yes, but I know the link. I can login with no problem.

Comment: What is db table prefix? is it wp_ or have you changed it? also is this a migrated version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the error logging in WordPress from the `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

After that, you will probably get some feedback inside:

```
wp-content/debug.log
```

Above that, you can try to get the exact feedback you get from 404 page.
Check the console in the inspector, and the response from te webserver.

```
curl -I http://yourwebsite.com/wp-login.php
```

Looks like inside your theme you have some redirecting problem. Try to remove the plugins, the theme and to set the 2017-teen new theme to check if this is true.

I hope you will isolate the issue soon.

---

#### What I suggest, you create the test environment somewhere and upgrade the website to the latest version of WordPress.

---

The other things you may investigate: (1) you may have the altered WordPress core somehow, and (2) you may have some .htaccess files other than the WordPress root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes are stupid as always. There was some unexpected .htaccess file in wp-admin folder witch says Deny All Everything and for Good.
Anyway thank you guys for your help!

Comment: I predicted this as a possible cause. Glad you were able to fix this out @Nemanja Đatkov. Not an easy fix.